# Describing the value to my overall well-being

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have a full-time job with salary and benefits. I work 3 12-hour days per week. The job is stressful and I have bosses monitoring every little action.

I have the opportunity to work overtime at this job on my off-days and get paid "x" amount of dollars per hour. Instead though, I choose to drive an Uber for "half x" dollars. It allows me to set my own hours, be my own boss, and have considerably less stress. I value these things more than the extra money that would be brought in from the overtime at my main job.

How can I best phrase how I get more life value out of the freedom and reduced stress than I would from twice the money? My first inclination is that it's something opposite "opportunity cost," but my brain seems to be stuck at this point to come up with better terminology.

Comment: You're assessing and prioritising your _quality of life_. I'd make this an answer, but I'm off to see our grandson :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, thank you, I don't know why I couldn't think of that. I will still entertain other people's suggestions to get some variety. Makes for better story-telling ;)

Comment: Shades, your own description in paragraph 2 is pretty good.

Comment: "In the big picture" or "Looking at the whole picture" or "All things considered" might be lead in phrases.  "In the big picture, less stress is worth making less money." I'm not sure that is as concise or complete as you're looking for in the phrases themselves though.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider ***wellness***.

Macmillan:

> **[wellness](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/wellness#wellness_3)**  *NOUN* [UNCOUNTABLE]
>
> physical, mental, and emotional health, usually including a healthy
>   way of living, such as a good diet and exercise

Comment: This phrase always makes me think of people in nursing homes, but that's just my own bias. +1